# Trying to create a loop that will iterate through a list and use the certain fields in that list as part of my commands for bowtie2

Tags: loops, unix, bioinformatics

First of all this is my first question here, I just signed up and I'm new to unix so excuse me if I did something wrong.

so okay, I have a file like this called fqfiles;

```
216     Slender 216_L8_1.fq.gz  216_L8_2.fq.gz
222     Stumpy  222_L8_1.fq.gz  222_L8_2.fq.gz
218     Slender 218_L8_1.fq.gz  218_L8_2.fq.gz
220     Stumpy  220_L8_1.fq.gz  220_L8_2.fq.gz
221     Stumpy  221_L8_1.fq.gz  221_L8_2.fq.gz
219     Slender 219_L8_1.fq.gz  219_L8_2.fq.gz
```

What I need to do is run the bowtie2 command for each of them, which has a syntax as;

```
bowtie2 -x Trypanosoma_brucei_brucei -1 216_L8_1.fq.gz -2 216_L8_2.fq.gz -S 216Slender.sam
```

So what I want to do is; for every line of that file use the first and the second field to make the last part of the code above, and the 3rd and 4th fields of the file as the middle part of the code.

```
awk '{print $1$2".sam"}' fqfiles
awk '{print -1, $3, -2, $4}' fqfiles
```

I can get those parts as this but I am just having a hard time making this a loop that will take the first line, take the fields of the first line, put it in the code, run it, then start over again for the next line etc.

Could anyone help me write this loop, or suggest what I should do about this?

Comment: something like `awk '{print "echo bowtie2 -x Trypanosoma_brucei_brucei -1 " $3 " " -2  " " $4 " " $1$2".sam"} file` . Once you are satisfied that commands are being generated correctly, remove the `echo` and redirect output to execute the cmds, like `awk '{print ....}' | bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `read` to read the file line by line:

```sh
while read -r n s f1 f2 ; do
    bowtie2 -x Trypanosoma_brucei_brucei -1 "$f1" -2 "$f2" -S "$n$s"
done < file
```